# What is the behaviour of lParam when WM_KEYDOWN message recived?

Tags: c++, winapi, lparam

I started learning winapi using c++ language.
I am trying to understand the `lParam` on WM_KEYDOWN message.

From the Microsoft documentation:

> **0-15**: The repeat count for the current message. The value is the number
>   of times the keystroke is autorepeated as a result of the user holding
>   down the key. If the keystroke is held long enough, multiple messages
>   are sent. However, the repeat count is not cumulative.
>
> **16-23**:    The scan
>   code. The value depends on the OEM.
>
> **24**: Indicates whether the key is an
>   extended key, such as the right-hand ALT and CTRL keys that appear on
>   an enhanced 101- or 102-key keyboard. The value is 1 if it is an
>   extended key; otherwise, it is 0.
>
> **25-28**: Reserved; do not use.
>
> **29**:The context code. The value is always 0 for a WM_KEYDOWN message.
>
> **30**: The previous key state. The value is 1 if the key is down before the
>   message is sent, or it is zero if the key is up.
>
> **31**: The transition state. The value is always 0 for a WM_KEYDOWN message.

I am handling this message by this way:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    cout << ((lParam & 0b11111111111111110000000000000000) >> 16) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000000000000001111111100000000) >> 8) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000000000000000000000010000000) >> 7) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000000000000000000000000000100) >> 2) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000000000000000000000000000010) >> 1) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000000000000000000000000000001) >> 0) << endl;
```

And if I press "A" button on my keyboard I get ouput:
`30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1`

If I hold "A" button I get muliple outputs:

```
16414, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
16414, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
16414, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

If I press other letter button, I get same result but with other first number. (For example, for "B" button I get 48 as simple press, 49200 as holding)

How can I understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't test this, but your bit ordering appears to be reversed. According to [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-message-flags), bits 0-15 are the LOW bits.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000000000000001111111111111111) >> 0) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000000111111110000000000000000) >> 16) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00000001000000000000000000000000) >> 24) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b00100000000000000000000000000000) >> 29) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b01000000000000000000000000000000) >> 30) << ", ";
    cout << ((lParam & 0b10000000000000000000000000000000) >> 31) << ", ";
```

Comment: Doesn't 0b00000000000000001111111111111111 reserse in memory automatic?

Comment: @don If it does (e.g. on a little-endian architecture), then both the literal as well as the value passed through `lParam` get *"reversed"*.

Comment: @Don2Quixote, In little endian, the values are stored in memory in reverse (by byte). When loaded into the register to do these operations, they are loaded in the proper order.

Comment: These are numbers, not bytes of memory being converted to a number. There is no "reverse" here. The numbers are just numbers. Endianness applies only when you store a number to memory and then read it back as bytes instead of as a number.